# How do I structure a Java project using maven modules?

Tags: java, maven, module, dependencies

I have a Java project that uses Maven for dependency management.

The main part of the project consists of a server, which initializes itself and then initializes its separate components.

For example

```
Server A
|
|___Component A
|   |___Sub-Component 1
|
|___Component B
|
|___Component C
|
...etc
```

Now each of these components will implement an interface contained in Server A. The interface defines a method initialize() which the server calls to start each of its components.

How would I handle this in maven?

In my mind Sub-Component 1 would be compiled first, then A, then B, then C, followed by Server A.

Comment: The whole beauty of Maven is that you don't have to define explicitly in what order things are built. You just define the dependencies. Server has a dependency on Component A, which has a dependency on Sub-Component 1. Maven will work out the rest

Comment: You are making a common beginner mistake of thinking that in maven parent-child relation means composition. In fact, a parent module does not depend on its children. The server and its component should be siblings in the maven directory structure. It’s hard to explain. Google: multi-module maven projects.

Comment: @MateuszStefek that makes sense; thank you. But what about the sub-components? Would those also be siblings to everything else?